# Can I use native C libraries from Vala?

Tags: vala, lame

I'm building a frontend for a LAME encoder in order to do a proof-of-concept in Gtk/Vala.

I've installed `libmp3lame-dev` and would like to simply encode a WAV file using a few given encoding parameters and graphically display the progress using a Gtk progress bar.

I can definitely figure out how to do that, but I'm not sure how to import `libmp3lame` into my Vala files and interface with the library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you need to use a VAPI to explain how to bind the C library to Vala.  The easy way to do this is using [GObject Introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection) to [generate the bindings automatically](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Bindings), but since LAME doesn't use GObject the only option is to write them by hand.  There is [some documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/LegacyBindings) of the process, and it tends to be much easier than writing wrappers for dealing with C in other languages, but it can still be somewhat intimidating for beginners—you should consider dropping by the #vala channel on GIMPnet to get help as you're developing the bindings.

That said, Vala includes bindings for [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/), which does include [an element](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-ugly-plugins/html/gst-plugins-ugly-plugins-lamemp3enc.html) for using LAME.  Were I in your shoes I would carefully consider using it before creating bindings for libmp3lame.